# Vue3 | Pinia - Watching storeToRefs in composable function does not work

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I'm trying to understand the purpose of composables. I have a simple composable like this and was trying to watch state from a Pinia store where the `watch` does not trigger:

```
import { ref, watch, computed } from "vue";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import useFlightsStore from "src/pinia/flights.js";
import usePassengersStore from "src/pinia/passengers.js";

export function useFlight() {
    const route = useRoute();

    const modalStore = useModalStore();
    const flightsStore = useFlightsStore();
    const { selection } = storeToRefs(flightsStore);

    const passengersStore = usePassengersStore();
    const { passengers, adults, children, infants } =
        storeToRefs(passengersStore);

    watch([adults, children, infants], (val) => console.log('value changes', val))
```

Where as the same thing in a Vue component works as expected.

So we **cannot** watch values inside composables?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you can watch values inside composables.

But, to watch a pinia state it has to be inside an arrow function:

`watch(() => somePiniaState, (n) => console.log(n, " value changed"));`

It's like watching a reactive object.

---

I believe this should be documented better. In Pinia documentation we can read how to watch the whole store or how to subscribe to a store but not how to watch a single state property inside a component or composable.

Also, the docs are somewhat shy in explaining that you can watch a property inside a store using `setup()` way of describing a store.

More on this here:
https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/794#discussioncomment-1643242

---

This error also silently fails (or does not execute), which is not helpful...

Comment: Tried this and still no results

Comment: Can confirm, so far state variables don't have any reactivity outside the store for me, but getters do though.

Comment: Is it using the option api?
I changed my code to use the script setup and the reactivity works out of the box. It's really easy to access states as well. It simplified my code a lot, even though I love the option api.

Comment: Where and how is the line with `watch(()=>somePiniaState...)` to be integrated in a component? A more detailed example would be nice...

Comment: In Vue 3 the syntax seem to have changed to `watch(somePiniaState, (n) => console.log(n, " value changed"));`. It wouldn't work for me using `() => somePiniaState`.

Answer (score 13):

I needed to watch a specific state attribute in one of my components but I didn't find my use case on [the official documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#subscribing-to-the-state).
I used a mix between a watch and storeToRefs to do it.

```
// Option API
<script>
import { usePlaylistsStore } from '@/stores/playlists'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
export default {
    name: 'PlaylistDetail',

    setup() {
        const playlistsStore = usePlaylistsStore()
        const { selectedGenres } = storeToRefs(playlistsStore)
        return { selectedGenres }
    },
    watch: {
        selectedGenres(newValue, oldValue) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
</script>

// Composition API
<script setup>
import { usePlaylistsStore } from '@/stores/playlists'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { computed, watch } from 'vue'

const playlistsStore = usePlaylistsStore()
const { selectedGenres } = storeToRefs(playlistsStore)

watch(() => selectedGenres, (newValue, oldValue) => {
    // do something
})
</script>
```

Comment: This also works with composition API.

Answer (score 4):

### There are 3 options for you to be able to use the watch in this context:

---

**Option 1: Return in setup**

```
    setup() {
        const store = useStore()
        const { piniaVariable } = storeToRefs(store)
        return { piniaVariable }
    },
    watch: {
        piniaVariable (newValue, oldValue) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

---

**Option 2: Direct Access**

```
watch: {
        'yourStore.piniaVariable' (newValue, oldValue) {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

---

**Option 3: Computed Property**

```
computed: {
    piniaVariable() {
        return useYourStore.piniaVariable
    }

    watch: {
        piniaVariable (newValue, oldValue) {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default watches in Vue are shallow watches. In order to watch the nested property change you have to set `deep` option of the `watch` to `true`.

```js
watch(state, (newState, oldState) => {
// do stuff
}, { deep: true})
```

[more on this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)