# Dialog box doesn't render while a pinia property was correctly togg

Tags: vuejs3, modal-dialog, pinia, vue-reactivity

I’m still learning using Vue 3 and Pinia. My program has a main component with a template that shows/hides a modal according to the value of a store boolean property called `PlaceModalStore.isShown`. In the main component, a ref called `isShown` takes reactively the same value of the property:
`const { isShown } = storeToRefs(PlaceModalStore)`
This ref is used in a v-if statement in the template of main component to show/hide the modal dialog box.

```
<teleport to="body">
    <transition name="fade">
        <PlaceTemplate v-if="isShown"/>
    </transition>
</teleport>
```

If I set this initial value of `PlaceModalStore.isShown` to `true`

```
export const usePlaceModalStore = defineStore('PlaceModalStore', {
    state: () => ({
        isShown: true,
...
}
```

the modal dialog box is rendered and I can make it go by clicking on a button: `@click=”PlaceModalStore.setPlaceModalHide”`. This toggles the value of PlaceModalStore.isShown to `false`. A watcher shows the ref `isShown` was toggled to false as expected. Everything seems fine but…

If I set the initial value of `PlaceModalStore.isShown` to `false` in `state:() ...`, the JS module runs and when the dialog box shall renders it calls `PlaceModalStore.setPlaceModalShow` that sets `PlaceModalStore.isShow` to `true`. A console.log statement shows this was correctly changed, but… the watcher doesn’t catch it and the modal dialog box is not rendered.

The store was created in main.js as follows:

```
const PlaceModalStore = usePlaceModalStore()
```

The code for the store is as follows:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const usePlaceModalStore = defineStore('PlaceModalStore' /* the unique ID */, {
  state: () => ({
    isShown: true,
    userHasSkipped: false,
    index: 0,
    message:
      'The location where the event occured was not found in my database. I was only able to determine the country name. Would you mind completing the information?',
    fullPlace: 'Porto Empedocle, UNK, Sicilia, Italia', // For testing
    city: 'Porto Empedocle', // For testing
    county: 'Agrigento', // For testing
    region: 'Sicilia', // For testing
    country: 'Italia', // For testing
  }),
  actions: {
    setPlaceModalShow() {
      this.isShown = true
      console.log("setPlaceModalShow() says PlaceModalShow changed to 'true'")
    },
    setPlaceModalHide() {
      this.isShown = false
      this.userHasSkipped = false
      console.log("setPlaceModalHide() says PlaceModalShow changed to 'false'")
    },
    setPlaceModalSkip() {
      this.isShown = false
      this.userHasSkipped = true
    },
    setPlaceModalContent(index, message, fullPlace, city, county, region, country) {
      this.index = index
      this.message = message
      this.fullPlace = fullPlace
      this.city = city
      this.county = county
      this.region = region
      this.country = country
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the call from the JS module is as simple as:

```
PlaceModalStore.setPlaceModalShow()
```

Thank for your help.

Edit-- It seems that the property `PlaceModalStore.iShown` might not be reactive. The console doesn't output anything after inserting this line in the main component.

```
watch(
  () => PlaceModalStore.isShown, (newValue) => {
     console.log('watch says property "isShown" has changed to: ', newValue);
  }
)
```

Comment: Would need to see more code. Please share what your store looks like, and how you call the actions in proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution with

```
const PlaceModalStore = usePlaceModalStore();
const isShown = computed(() => PlaceModalStore.isShown);
// You can use isShown in your template
```

You'll find other answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131716/12665127

Comment: Thank you @nom_unique, but this doesn't work either.  I used ```<script setup>```and the syntax I used seems to be correct.

I don't understand why usePlaceModalHide() works but not usePlaceModalShow=true()?

   ```setPlaceModalShow() {
      this.isShown = true
      console.log("setPlaceModalShow() says PlaceModalShow changed to 'true'")
    },
    setPlaceModalHide() {
      this.isShown = false
      this.userHasSkipped = false
      console.log("setPlaceModalHide() says PlaceModalShow changed to 'false'")
    },```

Comment: Sorry about that. I recreated your context on my side, here's a working solution if you're using <script setup>

Import your store as you already did:

const PlaceModalStore = usePlaceModalStore()

Then :

const isShown = computed(() => PlaceModalStore.isShown);

You can use your isShown computed property in your template. Computed allows PlaceModalStore.isShown to be "recalculated" when the value changes, making it reactive.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I arrived at the same solution too, but adding to the confusion, this only works when I write
```PlaceModalStore.isShown=true
this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log("Nothing to say")
}```
This was suggested by ChatGPT... The modal shows and works nicely BUT I get a
"[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler "
and a
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$nextTick')"
that does makes the code fail anyway.

Comment: I was happy to find at https://vuejs.org/api/general.html a confirmation of my intuition that nextTick() should be called by the property of the store: ```actions: {
    async setPlaceModalShow() {
      this.isShown = true
      console.log("setPlaceModalShow() says PlaceModalShow changed to 'true'... before nextTick")
      await nextTick()
      console.log("setPlaceModalShow() says PlaceModalShow changed to 'true'... after nextTick")
    },``` But this doesn't work in my case. The second console.log command is never executed. Why?